# How to link one item to another items?

Tags: c#, xml, mapping

I've numbers and latters in my XML file. Numbers consist of 4 items but can be increased and latters consist of the batch of the latters, what  i need to do is just get every items from Numbers and assign to its latters from Latters.

I came up with a solution below, but without any success, any help to fix it will be appreciated :)

```
class aWithItsB{
//It means that nextA stores 1 number and 
//nextLattersBs stores latters for each number according XML file. 
    public string nextA;
    public List<string> nextLattersBs = new List<string>();

    }

public class AB : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("D:\\new.xml");

        string lastNumber="";
        XmlNodeList numbers = doc.SelectNodes("AB/AandB/@numbers");
        XmlNodeList latters = doc.SelectNodes("AB/AandB/@latters");
        foreach(XmlNode number in numbers){
        if(number.Value!=lastNumber){
            foreach(XmlNode latter in latters){
            aWithItsBs AandB = new aWithItsB();
            AandB.nextA = number.Value;
            AandB.nextLattersB.Add(latter.Value);
                    print(number.Value + "" + latter.Value);
            }
        }
        lastNumber = number.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AB>
<AandB numbers ="1" latters = "a"></AandB>
<AandB numbers ="1" latters = "b"></AandB>
<AandB numbers ="1" latters = "c"></AandB>
<AandB numbers ="1" latters = "c"></AandB>
<AandB numbers ="2" latters = "b"></AandB>
<AandB numbers ="2" latters = "x"></AandB>
<AandB numbers ="3" latters = "y"></AandB>
<AandB numbers ="3" latters = "a"></AandB>
<AandB numbers ="3" latters = "z"></AandB>
<AandB numbers ="4" latters = "y"></AandB>
<AandB numbers ="4" latters = "x"></AandB>
<AandB numbers ="4" latters = "a"></AandB>
</AB>
```

Comment: "Letters" it is spelled "Letters".  MY EYES!!! AAAAH

Comment: Is it spelled *latters* or *letters*?  I think the latter.

Answer (score 1):

A helpful hint:

I believe you want to use a Dictionary or a Set for this task and not a list.

If you use a collection that does not allow multiples then you don't have to do as much logic.  You can check if an item is there and add it or not.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i took a look into the hints and i havent found it helpful to solve the problem. I definitely need to use a structure, and fix my current way, do you have the hints for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class NumberLetter
{
    public string Number {get; set;}
    public string Letter {get; set;}

    NumberLetter(string number, string letter)
    {
        Number = number;
        Letter = letter;
    }
}

public class AB : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {



        List<NumberLetter> myList = new List<NumberLetter>();
        myList.Add(new NumberLetter("2", "a"));
        myList.Add(new NumberLetter("2", "b"));
        myList.Add(new NumberLetter("2", "c"));
        // ...
        // writing
        sing (var sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\new.xml"))
        {
            var g = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<NumberLetter>));
            g.Serialize(sw, myList);
        }

        // reading
        using (var sr = new StreamReader("D:\\new.xml"))
        {
            var l = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<NumberLetter>));
            myList = (List<NumberLetter>)l.Deserialize(sr);
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, have tried it before posting here?